# Dynamic dispatch and threads

Tags: concurrency, rust

I'm currently playing around with concurrency in Rust and I've run into the following problem. Given a reference that doesn't have a concrete type, but one that uses dynamic dispatch it seems that it's not possible to call any function on it in a different thread. Here's a minimal example:

```
use std::thread;

trait T {
    fn func(&self);
}

struct S1;

impl S1 {
    pub fn new() -> S1 {
        S1
    }
}

impl T for S1 {
    fn func(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let reference: &T = &S1::new();
    thread::scoped(|| reference );
}
```

Trying to compile this leads to the following error:

```
uh@macaron:~$ rustc test.rs
test.rs:21:5: 21:19 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `T` [E0277]
test.rs:21     thread::scoped(|| reference );
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:21:5: 21:19 note: `T` cannot be shared between threads safely
test.rs:21     thread::scoped(|| reference );
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:21:5: 21:19 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `T` [E0277]
test.rs:21     thread::scoped(|| reference );
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:21:5: 21:19 note: `T` cannot be shared between threads safely
test.rs:21     thread::scoped(|| reference );
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I would have naively assumed that this would work as `S1` doesn't even have any data that could prevent it from being shared. So I assume I'm just setting it up wrong. Am I thinking correctly here and if so how do I get this to compile?

Comment: For pedantry and terminology's sake, `&T` is a *reference* to a `T`. Rust also has `*T`, which is a *raw pointer*, which is why it's useful to disambiguate the terms.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to use reference instead of pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that any S1 is `Sync`, but T doesn't carry that information. You have to make sure that `pointer` is `Sync` even in the absence of the info that it is S1. There are multiple ways to do this:

Make the trait always `Sync`:

```
trait T : Sync {
    fn func(&self);
}
```

Make the Pointer `T+Sync`:

```
fn main() {
    let pointer: &(T + Sync) = &S1::new();
    thread::scoped(|| pointer );
}
```

Use the actual type as the type of the pointer, either by stating it or by inference (this doesn't fit the question, but I want to document it for clarity):

```
fn main() {
    let pointer: &S1 = &S1::new();
    thread::scoped(|| pointer );
}

fn main() {
    let pointer = &S1::new();
    thread::scoped(|| pointer );
}
```